# How can I combine multiple displace modifiers?

Tags: animation, modifiers, image

I would like to create a scene where someone destroys an object (stone) with a pickaxe. With each hit the cracks are getting bigger until that stone will fall apart.

This is my plan for the cracks: I'd create 3 different images which show a procedure of these cracks. Then i'd use them in a displace modifier and try to adjust the timing when the pickaxe hits the stone.

But how can i combine two displace modifiers (i've used one for the stone itself, too) and make the cracks getting bigger and deeper?

Or is my way a bit too inconvenient. I think i could also try to use nodes, but i don't know which.

Comment: What is your reference? Is this like Minecraft, or uber-photorealistic?

Comment: It's more like minecraft, but the cracks should have an animation (spreading) when the pickaxe hits the stone and the cracks are 3d and not 2d as you can see in that game. So it's similar, but more realistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I think your project is better suited for **[shape keys](http://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys.html?highlight=shape%20keys)** here's a solution with displacement:

You can use multiple a displace modifiers on the same object, each one with a different image/texture as displacement and animate them separately.

Let's say you have 3 dsplacement maps:

[image]

By animating the strength on each one you can create transitions from one deformation to the next.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. That helped a lot. But do you know a way to spread these cracks beginning from the center? I mean if I'm correct that's the way it works in reality.

Comment: design your displacement maps to have the shapes you want

Comment: I don't mean that. Currently, these cracks just appear simultaneously or to say it better, the domain where the cracks appear should only happen after e.g. 0.2 sec. (it's further afar from the impact) it happens simultaneously with the rest domains. So it gives the viewer the impression that it only deforms like you'd deform clay. But in reality these cracks are spreading from the impact throughout the surface. May you know a way to create such an animation? (sorry if you're getting a bit annoyed by my questions).