# How to use two displacement material in one plane?

Tags: displacement, vertex-colors

I was making a terrain, actually making a path on the terrain,so I have to combine two materials together with their own displacement maps.

Now I know how to do it for those normal materials, I just weight paint the terrain to create a vertex color, add an node called *Attribute* and chose the vertex color. Therefore I get two materials on one plane except the displacement material.

But how to do it with displacement? It's in the modifier so I can't use the *Attribute* node for it, or can I?

And in the displace modifier, I do find a place I can choose to put a vertex group(not the vertex color) to have two displacement maps, but it is not the *Vertex Color* that I weight painted before.

Comment: Hello :). Wouldn't it be easier to just combine both displacement maps using nodes?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/multiple-texture-displacements-mapping-in-one-scene/44927#44927
and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/how-can-i-combine-multiple-displace-modifiers?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144017/how-to-combine-the-bump-maps-of-two-texture-maps?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You could do everything inside the shader nodes with vectod displacement and masks.